# Estimating a VAR model with variable coefficients

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autoregressive, finance, vector-autoregression

I want to estimate a VAR model based on the Dufour and Engle [paper](http://weber.ucsd.edu/~mbacci/engle/291.pdf) "Time and the Price Impact of a Trade" (2000).

There, the parameter $ b_{i} $ of the endogenous variable $ x_{i} $ is dependent on the strictly exogenous variable $ T_{t-i} $ :

$$ b_{i}x_{t-i}=[ \gamma_{i} +\delta_{i} T_{t-i} ] x_{t-i} \ \ (1) $$

The authors state, that they estimated this system by OLS, but I am not quite sure how the estimator looks like in this case. I thought of multiplying out the equation and defining a new variable, say $ z_{t-i} $

$$    \gamma_{i} x_{t-i} +\delta_{i} [ T_{t-i}  x_{t-i}] = \gamma_{i} x_{t-i} +\delta_{i}  z_{t-i} $$

which would consist of an exogenous and endogenous part though, which I think makes this procedure methodically incorrect. Can anybody give an explanation how such a system as in (1) is estimated using OLS?
I plan to use the vars-Package in R btw.

Comment: The link is broken, can you fix that? I found another version of this paper and glanced through it. I did not find the problem you mention, could you be more precise where exactly this statement was stated in the paper?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here's another link to the [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.31.9325&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
You find the equation on page 14 (2480) as part of a longer equation. My idea was to multiply it out and regress on z as an exogeneous variable (which hasn't an own equation in the VAR).